# Visual Studio Portable

Tags: visual-studio, portability

Is there any portable version of Visual Studio (2005, 2008, 2010..)? Is it possible to use VS on a computer without installing the whole package? Virtual machines or alternative IDEs such as SharpDevelop are unfortunately out of the question.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not certain what exactly is your problem - what do you mean by using VS w/o installing whole package? What do you mean by portable - do you mean a version that can run on devices with small form factors than typical desktops/laptops/netbooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any VS portable edition. But if you're planning this "purely" for compiling C#/VB.net code, you should be aware that any computer with .net framework installed contains its compilers (C# and VB.net)

Comment: Either the VS full or express need to be installed through the normal install package, there is no other supported method of installation. Why would you need another method? The solutions are portable from any given VS install. And like Yoni pointed out, you can use any text editor (notepad++ requires no installation and I believe has text highlighting for most if not all VS languages) and compile with the provided .net compilers.

Comment: Thank you, but what I need is more than just compiling. I can't install VS to my computer right now, and I need to write/test some code using some VS features. Of course I can use notepad++ eg., I was just curious if there is any "Visual Studio Portable" like "MS Office Portable", but I guess there isn't any.